# How to perform database queries in async microservices?

Tags: database, microservices, messaging

I have problem with one concept about async microservices.

Assume that all my services are subscribe to some event bus, and I have exposed API Gateway which takes HTTP request and translate them to AMQP protocol.

How to handle GET requests to my API Gateway? Should I use RPC? For single entity it’s ok, but what about some search or filtering (eg. get games by genre from Games service)?

I’m thinking about using RPC for getting single entities by ids and creating separate Search service with Elastic which will expose some GET endpoints to API Gateway. But maybe somewhere it’s simpler solution for my problem. Any ideas?

Btw., It’s correct to translate HTTP requests from API Gateway to AMQP messages?

Comment: I understand that the microservices don't have any querying capabilities, right? Or they have but they respond only using events?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [Event Sourcing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591559.aspx) and [CQRS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554200.aspx). You can also take a look at my personal coding project:

[image]